# Restricting page count when printing

Tags: css, print-css

Is there any way that I can use CSS to restrict the number of pages that will print?

For example, I have an HTML template which is 2 pages long, dynamically filled with specific fields from my database. If anything causes the content to wrap onto a 3rd page, I still only want it to print on 2 pages, and omit the 3rd.

I was looking at the `@page` rule, thinking I could do something with pseudo selectors however it only appears to support `:first`, `:last`, `:left` and `:right`.

Any ideas?

Comment: @page:last display:none? Or visibility?

Comment: @Chocoprins18 I haven't tested it, but MDN suggests that most styles are ignored within `@page` rules ( 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page )

Comment: I can only think about setting your html/body to 2 pages height and then `overflow:hide` on it to hide everything else.